# Frechet differentiability along sequences

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

For normed spaces $X,Y$, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is differentiable at $x$ if there is $L\in L(X,Y)$ (linear bounded operator) such that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-L(h)}{|h|_X}=0 \quad (A)$$

Given a candidate $L\in L(X,Y)$ is it true that one can check, for all sequences $h_k\rightarrow_X0$, the condition: $$\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x+h_k)-f(x)-L(h_k)}{|h_k|_X}=0 \quad (B)$$

to then conclude differentiability?

Suppose in fact that $(A)$ doesn't hold. Then there is $\epsilon$ such that for all $\delta$ one can find $|h_\delta|_X \leq\delta$ with $\displaystyle  \left | \frac{f(x+h_\delta)-f(x)-L(h_\delta)}{|h_\delta|_X}\right |\geq \epsilon$.

Therefore one can find $h_k$ going to zero, with $\displaystyle  \left | \frac{f(x+h_k)-f(x)-L(h_k)}{|h_k|_X}\right |\geq \epsilon$. This contradicts $(B)$, so $(B)\implies (A)$.

But does $(A)$ imply $(B)$? I was thinking about the following, could this work? Take a sequence $h_k\rightarrow 0$. Then, fix $\epsilon$. Find $\delta(\epsilon)$ with the difference quotient in $(A)$ smaller than $\epsilon$ for $|h|_X\leq \delta (\epsilon)$. Also, find $K(\delta(\epsilon))$ such that for $k\geq K(\delta(\epsilon))$ we have $|h_k|\leq \delta(\epsilon)$. This should yield the claim.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem. Everything happens in a metric space, so we can use sequences to compute limits.

Comment: By the way, you are here dealing with the specific question of differentiability, but the result holds for limits in general. Hence in this specific case.

Comment: This obviously holds. This is the same as continuity being equivalent to sequential continuity. You can either look at all sequences or at one continuous variable.